# Necesito conectar un PHP con QT c++

Tags: php, c++, base-de-datos, qt

estoy haciendo un registro de usuarios, y tambien un logueo, en QT con c++, acabo de crear un php el cual tengo alojado en un hosting, donde tengo la base de datos, lo que no se es como enviar los datos que registra el usuario en mi aplicacion, enviarlo a la base de datos online, o que puedo utilizar

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html

Comment: Deberías visitar [help], para ver como hacer una buena pregunta. Para poder ayudarte, debería poner el código que has intentado, sino es posible que te cierren la pregunta.